# Showing that a subset of a ring with a certain property is a union of prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, prime-numbers, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Any subset $S $ of a ring $R$ such that $xy \in S \implies x \in S$ or $y \in S$ is a union of prime ideals of $R$.

Prime ideals of a ring are defined as those $I$ such that $xy \in I \implies x \in I, y \in I$.  This property extends easily to unions of prime ideals.

Is the converse true?  If $S \subset R$ has the prime property, then is $S$ a union of prime ideals?

In other words,

The set of prime ideals form a basis for open sets in a topology on $R$.  Define $S \subset \Bbb{R}$ to be a *prime subset* if it has the prime property $xy \in S \implies x \in S$ or $y \in S$.  Then are prime subsets always the open sets generated by the prime ideals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for example take $R=\Bbb Z$. Then $\Bbb Z\setminus 2\Bbb Z$ has the prime property but there is no ideal which contains $1$ and does not contain $2$.

Comment: Another example could be the units of a commutative ring.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest counter-example is $R=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ and $S=\{-1\}$: If $x,y\in\{0,1\}$, then also $xy\in\{0,1\}$.